# Error when using onmouseover within an img tag within a php echo statement

Tags: php, html, onmouseover

I've been trying to make a button that changes into a different image once rolled over with the mouse, but the code being inside of an echo command has caused some complications.  This is the php code I tried to use, which otherwise simply displays the image when the onmouse functions are removed:

```
if ($pg > 0) { echo ('<div class="next"><a href="?pg='.($pg-1).'"><img src="/images/prevpage.gif" onmouseover="this.src='/images/prevpagehl.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='/images/prevpage.gif';"/></a></div>'); }
```

Using this code causes the following error to appear:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/wintblxq/public_html/index.php on line 145

Are there any changes to the syntax I can make to get this to function properly, or do I need to attempt a new approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes (your ticks actually):

```
if ($pg > 0) { 
    echo '<div class="next"><a href="?pg='.($pg-1).'"><img src="/images/prevpage.gif" onmouseover="this.src=\'/images/prevpagehl.gif\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/images/prevpage.gif\';"/></a></div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes in the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` javascript:

```
if ($pg > 0) 
{ 
    echo ('<div class="next"><a href="?pg='.($pg-1).'"><img src="/images/prevpage.gif" onmouseover="this.src=\'/images/prevpagehl.gif\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/images/prevpage.gif\';"/></a></div>'); 
}
```

PHP is confusing these with the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to escape your single quotes with a Backslash example:

```
<?php echo '<p onmouseover="alert(\\'SIngle Quotes\\');">YAY</p>';
```

An easier way to write php and to see it (In my Opinion) is to Seperate HTML from php. With your code here is how i would write it.

```
<?php if ($pg > 0) { // PHP Scripts ?>
    <!-- HTML Tags and text -->
    <div class="next"><a href="?pg=<?php $pg-1  // MORE PHP CODE WITHIN HTML ?>"><img src="/images/prevpage.gif" onmouseover="this.src='/images/prevpagehl.gif';" onmouseout="this.src='/images/prevpage.gif';"/></a></div>

 <?php }  ?>
```

This way you don't have to worry about escaping all of your single quotes, and you can see it nicer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to get the hang of using HTML with PHP tags and this helps me quite a bit.